# "QtRunWork" task returned false but did not log an error. (Unknown compiler flavor)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

Im working on a Qt project. Everything has been working perfectly untill I opened application this morning. I got error: "QtRunWork" task returned false but did not log an error. Im using VS2019 with QtExtension.

This is output:

```
1>Moc'ing ..\src\mainwindow.h...
1>Moc'ing ..\src\settingsdialog.h...
1> moc: Unknown compiler flavor 'msvc;msvc'; valid values are: msvc, unix.
1> Usage: C:/Qt/5.15.1/msvc2019_64/bin/moc [options] [header-file] [@option-file] [MOC generated json file]
1> Qt Meta Object Compiler version 67 (Qt 5.15.1)
1> Options:
1>   -?, -h, --help                    Displays help on commandline options.
1>   --help-all                        Displays help including Qt specific
1>                                     options.
1>   -v, --version                     Displays version information.
1>   -o <file>                         Write output to file rather than stdout.
1>   -I <dir>                          Add dir to the include path for header
1>                                     files.
1>   -F <framework>                    Add Mac framework to the include path for
1>                                     header files.
1>   -E                                Preprocess only; do not generate meta
1>                                     object code.
1>   -D <macro[=def]>                  Define macro, with optional definition.
1>   -U <macro>                        Undefine macro.
1>   -M <key=value>                    Add key/value pair to plugin meta data
1>   --compiler-flavor <flavor>        Set the compiler flavor: either "msvc" or
1>                                     "unix".
1>   -i                                Do not generate an #include statement.
1>   -p <path>                         Path prefix for included file.
1>   -f <file>                         Force #include <file> (overwrite default).
1>   -b <file>                         Prepend #include <file> (preserve default
1>                                     include).
1>   --include <file>                  Parse <file> as an #include before the main
1>                                     source(s).
1>   -n <which>                        Do not display notes (-nn) or warnings
1>                                     (-nw). Compatibility option.
1>   --no-notes                        Do not display notes.
1>   --no-warnings                     Do not display warnings (implies
1>                                     --no-notes).
1>   --ignore-option-clashes           Ignore all options that conflict with
1>                                     compilers, like -pthread conflicting with
1>                                     moc's -p option.
1>   --output-json                     In addition to generating C++ code, create
1>                                     a machine-readable JSON file in a file that
1>                                     matches the output file and an extra .json
1>                                     extension.
1>   --collect-json                    Instead of processing C++ code, collect
1>                                     previously generated JSON output into a
1>                                     single file.
1>   --output-dep-file                 Output a Make-style dep file for build
1>                                     system consumption.
1>   --dep-file-path <file>            Path where to write the dep file.
1>   --dep-file-rule-name <rule name>  The rule name (first line) of the dep file.
1> Arguments:
1>   [header-file]                     Header file to read from, otherwise stdin.
1>   [@option-file]                    Read additional options from option-file.
1>   [MOC generated json file]         MOC generated json output
1>Moc'ing ..\src\deviceManager.h...
1>Moc'ing ..\src\treemodel.h...
1>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild\qt_globals.targets(268,5): error MSB4181: The "QtRunWork" task returned false but did not log an error.
1>Done building project "project.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I've tried changing compiler flavor but have not managed to do it. I tried changing it in Qt Project Settings, but it did not do anything. Thank you for your time.

Edit: Out of about 20 .h I've tracked the one that gives this error when trying to compile in VS2019 using Qt Extension. Have no idea how to fix this error.

Comment: This is looking suspicious: `1> moc: Unknown compiler flavor 'msvc;msvc'; valid values are: msvc, unix.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I uninstalled the Qt VS tool from Visual Studio and install the previous version of Qt VS tool.

You can find it here: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/2.5.2/

That works for me. Maybe a problem with the new version.

Edit: Don't forget to disable auto-update.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks for sharing the link!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.

Accidentally I had a normal `int` declared under my `public slots:`. Moving it into normal `public:` worked for me and resolved the issue.

Hopefully this will work for you as well.

Comment: Cheers, missing semi-colon in public slots declaration. Was in output window, not in error list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio and I got the same message in `Error List` tab. I have to go to the `Output` tab to see what really caused this error.

For me, it's because that it will reference an image file in one of my qrc files but the image file doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Helped to overload the Q_OBJECT macro
It was

```
class CXXX: public CTTT
{
  Q_OBJECT
```

Has become

```
class CXXX: public CTTT
{
  //Q_OBJECT
```